# REPORT- AUDIT LOG in Google Admin console

Tags: google-apps-script

Can we pull all Report names using google apps script in spreadsheet from REPORT- AUDIT LOG in Google Admin console

Comment: Hey @Manju, which data are you trying to export into your Spreadsheet exactly? There are many audit log's, including Admin, Calendar, Login, etc. What do you mean by Report names? Cheers

Comment: The admin report..there are many admin reports  which i can download from admin console. but i want to write a script in google apps to populate the list ( all reports) in spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain data from reports using the [Admin SDK Reports Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-reports).

As an example:

```js
/**
 * Generates a login activity report for the last week as a spreadsheet. The
 * report includes the time, user, and login result.
 */
function generateLoginActivityReport() {
  var now = new Date();
  var oneWeekAgo = new Date(now.getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  var startTime = oneWeekAgo.toISOString();
  var endTime = now.toISOString();

  var rows = [];
  var pageToken;
  var page;
  do {
    page = AdminReports.Activities.list('all', 'login', {
      startTime: startTime,
      endTime: endTime,
      maxResults: 500,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var items = page.items;
    if (items) {
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i];
        var row = [
          new Date(item.id.time),
          item.actor.email,
          item.events[0].name
        ];
        rows.push(row);
      }
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);

  if (rows.length > 0) {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('G Suite Login Report');
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

    // Append the headers.
    var headers = ['Time', 'User', 'Login Result'];
    sheet.appendRow(headers);

    // Append the results.
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, headers.length).setValues(rows);

    Logger.log('Report spreadsheet created: %s', spreadsheet.getUrl());
  } else {
    Logger.log('No results returned.');
  }
}
```

Upon calling [`AdminReports.Activities.list`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list), there are three parameters:

1. **userKey**: It identifies the user to audit. The special value `all` represents all the users in the domain.
2. **applicationName**: Application name for which the events are to be retrieved (category within the admin logs UI). The acceptable values are: access_transparency, admin, calendar, drive, gplus, group, groups_enterprise, login, mobile, rules, token, user_accounts.
3. **options**: Other parameters that the request may take. You can find more information in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list) of the endpoint.

Comment: Thanks carlesgg97. I put the parameter for applicationName as 'admin' and trying to get the item.events[0].name. It does not bring me correct "even name". Also, I do not see the parameter to obtain the "event description" of the reports.

Comment: Hey @ManjuParihar, item.events[0].name should get you the correct Event name, as according to the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list#items.events.name). Regarding the event description message - that is not possible through the API, as the response does not include such a field. However, those messages are generated using the data obtained by the response. You can see an example [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/admin-chrome-os-settings), in the "Admin Console message format" field. Cheers.

Comment: Hello @ManjuParihar kindly consider [upvoting/accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if my answer was of any use for you. Cheers!